# how to display icon in a cell of a grid view c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, icons

I want to Display an icon in the particular cell.

I am using this code. I have commented where i want to display the icon:

```
string lastScripDate = this.GetLastScripDate(sFolderPath, pb);
string sQuery = "select * from database";
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table = this.Retrieve_Data(sQuery, "database");
pb.Maximum = table.Rows.Count;
pb.Value = 0;
double num = 0.0;
double num2 = 0.0;
double num3 = 0.0;
double num4 = 0.0;
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        dgv.Rows.Add();
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Sname"].Value = table.Rows[i]["Symbol"].ToString();
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["clsprice"].Value = table.Rows[i]["SCRIP"].ToString();
        string str3 = table.Rows[i]["TradeType"].ToString();
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["trd"].Value = str3;
        string str4 = str3;
        if (str4 != null)
        {
            if (!(str4 == "p"))
            {
                if (str4 == "q")
                {
                    goto Label_01DD;
                }
            }
            else
            {
               dgv.Rows[i].Cells["trd"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;///////I Want to Display Icon in this Cell(Up.Ico)
            }
        }
        goto Label_020B;
    Label_01DD:

        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Trade"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;///////////////An Want to Display Icon in this Cell also(Down.Ico

    Label_020B:
    dgv.Rows[i].Cells["date"].Value = table.Rows[i]["TDate"].ToString();
        num = Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[i]["CPrice"]);
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["tp"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00}", num);
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[i]["Price"]);
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["tp"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00}", num2);
        num3 = Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[i]["Loss"]);
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells["sl"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00}", num3);
        try
        {
            num4 = Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[i]["Ratio"]);
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Ratio"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00}", num4);
        }
        catch
        { }
        pb.Value++;
    }
    if (pb.Value == pb.Maximum)
    {
        pb.Value = pb.Minimum;
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: For future question please consider providing significantly smaller code samples (10 lines of code is usually enough). Avoid using `goto` in code provided for other people to read as it usage of it is normally frowned upon and may decrease chances of getting targeted answer.

Comment: **Goto** is not good pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to acheive this would be to add [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.aspx) and then set icon to that cell. Here is a sample

```
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn());
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);

        DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];

        Icon ic = new Icon("icon.ico");

        cell.Value = ic;
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - create some icons inside a property class
Example

```
    public static class EIcons
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// NULL
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Icon NOICON       = new Icon("Icon/null.ico");


        /// <summary>
        /// NEW
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Icon NEW          = new Icon("Icon/new.ico");
   }
```

2 - Create a property for your datagrid, that contains strings, or int, and also ICONS objects.
The constructor must always initialize your icon to something consistent.

```
    public class GridProperty01
    {
           /// <summary>
           /// CONSTRUCTOR - factory initialization
           /// </summary>
           public GridProperty01()
           {
              ID = 0;
              NewValue = string.Empty;
              Alert = EIcons.NOICON;      // solid icon initialization. Create transparent icon if you wish...
           }

           public int ID { get; set; }     
           public string NewValue { get; set; }  
           public Icon Alert { get; set; }        // for icon

    }
```

3 - Create a list of data and assign to your icon property the icon you need. At last bind the list to your datagrid, and refresh.
All this code must be put inside a button of SEARCH for example, or inside a method that update the gridview..

```
  // GET - data for datagridview
  List<GridProperty01> tempList = new List<GridProperty01>();

  for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; ++jj) {
     // INIT
     GridProperty01 tempObj = new GridProperty01();
     // GET - data 
     tempObj.ID = jj;  // your code...
     tempObj.NewValue = "xxx"; // your code...
     tempObj.Alert = EIcons.NEW;  // an icon...
     // SET - insert row to list
     tempList.Add(tempObj);
  }


  // SET - assign list to your gridview
  dataGridView01.DataSource = tempList; 
  // SET - refresh
  dataGridView01.Update();
  dataGridView01.Refresh();
```

I suppose that's enough.
In addition, if you plan to SORT the Icon column when the column header has been clicked, create an Icon Text property, that contains different "text" accordingly to your Icon property. At the sort use this string to sort the rows of the datagrid. In this case, you should have:

```
// example code..
Alert = EIcons.NEW;
AlertText = "new";

Alert = EIcons.NOICON;
AlertText = "noicons";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it by using [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/119222d6-0189-49ab-a01a-c5eeb201723e)